# Change programmatic access Options in Outlook 2013

Tags: powershell, outlook

I use Outlook 2013, and Powershell scripts.

How can I change **programmatically** using *Powershell* the programmatic-access-options in Outlook 2003?

Comment: http://www.slipstick.com/developer/change-programmatic-access-options

Comment: Well I guess you have to change some registry values as explained in the link you added ?

Comment: So you are tryin to work around the security prompts? See http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52 for the list of your options.

Answer (score 0):

This works for a local or remote host (tested on Windows 10 with Office 2016):

```
#config
$computerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$hive = "LocalMachine"
#replace 16.0 with 15.0 for Outlook 2013, 14.0 for Outlook 2010 and 12.0 for Outlook 2007
$regPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook"

#if remote computer is reachable
if(Test-Connection $computerName -Quiet -Count 2 -ErrorAction 0) {
    try {
        #open remote registry
        $base = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::$hive, $ComputerName)

        #open desired key with edit permission
        $key = $base.OpenSubKey($regPath, $true)

        #if Security subkey does not exist
        if($key.GetSubKeyNames() -notcontains "Security") {

            #create Security subkey
            $key.CreateSubKey("Security") | Out-Null
        }

        #open Security subkey
        $subkey = $key.OpenSubKey("Security", $true)

        #set or create ObjectModelGuard value
        $subkey.SetValue("ObjectModelGuard", 2, "Dword")

        #close subkey, key and registry connection
        $subkey.Close()
        $key.Close()
        $base.Close()
    } catch {
        Throw "Remote registry is not accessible (check `$hive and `$regPath)."
    }
} else {
    Throw "Remote computer is not reachable."
}
```